# c# detect timer in form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer

I'm using C#, WinForms, I created a button on my form where I dynamically create a timer.  I have another button where I need to check how many timers I created.

I tried to cancel the timer in the form but it does not work, here is the code:

```
int i=0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = update;
    timer.Tag = i;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);            
    timer.Start();
    timer.Enabled = true;
    i++;
}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (var controllo in this.Controls)
    {
        if (controllo is Timer)
        {
            Timer item = (Timer)controllo;
            if (timer.Tag ==1)
            {
                item.Stop();
                item.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Timer is not a control so can't be found back through the Controls collection.  Drop one from the toolbox onto your form and look at the InitializeComponent() method to see the correct code.  Note the usage of `this.components`.

Comment: It doesn't exist, you aren't holding a reference to it so you are making zombie objects.

Comment: What are you trying to do with all those timer tick events ?

Comment: i added the timer in a list, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't add the newly created timer to form.controls. That's the looping failed to find the control, I suggest you to add the timers to the Form control like the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    // code here
    this.Controls.Add(timer);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<Timer>())
    {
        if (ctrl.Tag ==1)
        {
            ctrl.Stop();
            ctrl.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use a List and Add the newly created timers to the list and at later points you can iterate through the `List<Timer>` instead for Lopping through all controls. Which means the code will be like this following:

```
List<Timer> TimerList =new List<Timer>();
int i=0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    // code here
    TimerList.Add(timer);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (Timer t in GlobalTimers)
     {
           if (t.Tag ==1)
           {
               t.Stop();
               t.Dispose();
           }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain Global List of Timer in form

```
List<Timer> GlobalTimers=new List<Timer>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = update;
        timer.Tag = i;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);            
        timer.Start();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        GlobalTimers.Add(timer);
     }


  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      foreach (var item in GlobalTimers)
      {
            if (item.Tag ==1)
            {
                item.Stop();
                item.Dispose();
            }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer do not ship nothing new to @un-lucky answer

Comment: Yea because that dude just copied my code look at      foreach (Timer t in GlobalTimers)
     { this line he never init that Variable

Comment: if i use this      foreach (Timer item in GlobalTimers) it works thanks!